# Ionic3 app with firebase authentication logs user automatically out after 24 hours (login doesn't persist)

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, ionic3, angularfire2

I've launched a few commercial android & ios apps using ionic3 and the firebase javascript angularfire2 authentication. I am starting to receive user complaints about users having to relog in after some time. After some time (feels like > 24 hours of inactivity in the app) the user gets log'd out. Most of the complaints are around IOS apps. while some other ios users have reported inactivity for over weeks and still remain to be log'd in in the same app. These use-cases seem random, and maybe they are, I added them here just to be complete.

Code I use is very straightforward and according to the docs.

```
    this.afAuth.auth.setPersistence('LOCAL'); 
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(
        (user) => {
            if (!user) {
                //Logout
                this.logout.next({});
            }
            else {
                //Login
                this.authenticated.next(user);
            }
        }
    );
```

logout & authenticated are Subjects.

Things I've done to try to solve it:

- Setting the persistant state to local. Eventhough firebase now indicates that this is no longer necessary. There isn't any option in firebase project anymore to specify session length.
- Updating everything to the last version.
- Manually refreshing or storing token shouldn't be necessary according to latest firebase docs.

Things I can still try out:

- Should a background refresh plugin help to not let the session token expire? (eventhough firebase claims it doesn't expire)?
- is there a conflict between import * from firebase; and angularFire2?

ionic 3.9.2
firebase 4.10.1
angularfire2 5.0.0-rc.6

Anyone else experiencing problems around persistent login? Or tips how to solve this?

UPDATE:
This only affects IOS where the user is near space limits, see below remarks.

Answer (score 2):

There was an issue with `localStorage` being unreliable (cleared on low memory) in iOS devices for Cordova apps. Switch to Firebase version `4.13.0` which now uses `indexedDB` to store the Auth state. This is more reliable and should persist in such situations.

Comment: Dear @bojeil, wow your fast, 4.13.0 has been released 10 hours ago. thanks for your quick tip. I've heard about the problems with localStorage. Yesterday I was with a customer experiencing the relogin problems and checked his disc usage on his iphone 7. He still had 0.5G free. So it wasn't full, but stil on the high side to maybe provoke the garbage collection. I will test your tip about upgrading, but it can take some time before I have some results. Where did you find the release notes of 4.13.0, I can't find them on their github nor on their site.Thank you for your tip!

Comment: Found the release notes: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js are you sure it is the js firebase 4.13.0 that now supported indexDB and not the IOS one?

Comment: 4.12.0 starting supporting them but there were some issues with that which were fixed in 4.13.0. I am referring to the JS library.

Comment: Thanks I am unable to test with 4.13.0 or 4.13.1 as it give me memory errors. I've made a firebase-js ticket: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/714 I am able to use 4.12.1 but as you stated 3.13 solves some issues.

Comment: Unfortunately after upgrading to 5.0.3 problems with a handful of same users still persist. Any tips for troubleshooting? It would be great if I could see for those users what the reason was they got log'd out by the system.

Comment: indexedDB may not be available in iOS Cordova. Try using this polyfill library by Microsoft: https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-plugin-indexedDB

Comment: Thanks gonna try it out. Any tips on how to troubleshoot. Any server side log that can help me determine why a user got log'd out?

Comment: I think this is a client side issue. `localStorage` seems to have some issues in iOS devices for Cordova apps. The Auth state is stored there but if that gets cleared, the user is considered signed out.

Comment: After updateing firebase to > 4.13.1 and using github.com/Microsoft/cordova-plugin-indexedDB in July the complaints persist only for IOS with high disc space usage. I've now replicated the problem on my IOS phone as well. After clearing up space it works again. But it is still a negative customer experience while other apps stay log'd in. Any update or direction for this?